# a is null in my Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

I put javascript code in my main.js file. With the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/Rochefort/Q7Vwg/ (Can't copy my code here)

But checking in Firebug, I get this error:

''a is null'' in 29. line.

[image]

What's my problem?

Comment: Which line 29, which file? My crystal ball is defect - does not seem to be in the code you posted... apparently your problem is a failure to debug :-)

Comment: "Whats my problem?" - we don't read minds

Comment: Is this YOUR file, or where does it come from? A small piece of minified code does not help the investigation much. Also check the trace (function call stack - click the "+")!

Comment: That's Google Maps JS code. I've seen this error somewhere (on SO) before. Will need to time to find that again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a is null` usually means your map is not initialized and you are trying to use it

Answer (score 2):

I got this error once. Make sure the map script runs only on pages using the map. You can check if the map exists by using an "if". Something like this:

```
if ($('mapClass').length>0) { 
   // here you run the google maps functions 
}
```